# How to access methods and fields of the nested class from enclosing template class?

Tags: c++, templates, nested, friend-class

I've searched through the web an didn't find any explanation why the following happens.

For example, there is a template class Enclosing with a nested class Nested.

In Enclosing class, there is a method that should create an instance of the Nested class and use it's fields and methods.

In the following code, there is a model of how I'm trying to do it:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
class Enclosing{
public:
    class Nested;
    Nested foo();
};

template<typename T, typename S>
class Enclosing<T,S>::Nested{
public:
    T field;
    void some_method();
    friend class Enclosing;    // instead of this line I also tried:
                               // friend class Enclosing<T,S> 
                               // and it didn't work either
};

template<typename T, typename S>
typename Enclosing<T,S>::Nested Enclosing<T,S>::foo (){
    Nested nes;
    nes.some_method;         // the problem appears here
    return enc;
}
```

The problem is:

When I'm writing `nes.some_method`, none of the environments I tried (VS2010, eclipse), after I type "nes.", doesn't propose me any options. I seems like "nes" is not an instanse of the class at all.

How to access methods and fields of the nested class from enclosing template class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
Nested nes();
```

Does not create an object of type `nes`, but rather *declares a function* which takes no arguments and returns an object of type `Nested`. I suspect this to be the source of your problem, not the `friend` declaration. Just remove the pair of parentheses after `nes`:

```
Nested nes;
```

Alternatively, in C++11 you may do:

```
Nested nes{};
```

**EDIT:**

After fixing the above error, it still seems your program does not compile & link correctly - doubtfully because of the same problem. What I can tell from your code is that a definition of the `some_method()` member function is still missing, and that may be a reason for the linker to refuse creating the executable for your program.

Comment: I would really like to know what it is that leads people to making this error so frequently.  I honestly don't ever remember doing this, yet somebody posts about it almost every day.

Comment: @RyanWitmer The default constructor of a class takes no arguments, so beginners commonly get the misconception that they're calling the default constructor when instantiating an object. The syntax to it is also similar to calling a specialized constructor, which adds to the confusion.

Comment: I just tried to remove parentheses and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Grinch: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? There's 101 ways something cannot work, I cannot guess which one it is ;) Does it not compile? Does it not link? Does it crash? If it is a compiler error or linker error, what is the exact error message that you are seeing?

Comment: @Grinch: For instance, [this compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/dsmG8R). Notice, that I had to add a definition for `some_method()`, which was not shown in your original code.

Comment: @AndyProwl : Well, your example shows me that there is no problem :) at least, in the place I thought it is.

Comment: @Grinch: OK, glad I could help at least in part ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Nested nes();
```

You're not calling the default constructor of `Nested` but rather declaring a function named `nes` that takes 0 arguments and returns by value an instance of the `Nested` class. This is referred to as the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Remove the parameters to get the code to function properly.

Here is a working [demo](http://ideone.com/eAEmQI#view_edit_box).